# Can't set focus to textbook with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This one has been driving me nuts and I have no clue what the problem is.

I have a quiz that has different kinds of question types (multiple choice, type in the answer, etc) and for each question, I set the innerHTML using a function and then populate it accordingly.

If it's a textbox question, I'd like to automatically set the focus to it. I've tried using javascript, jQuery, and the console window from within Chrome. I've set the tab index to -1. I've looked on this website, but none of the solutions seem to work.

Here's the code:

```js
function populate(){
    render_HTML(session.getCurrentItem().itemType);
    if(session.getCurrentItem().itemType === "multiple choice"){
      //multiple choice 
    }
    else if(session.getCurrentItem().itemType === "typing"){
      var element = document.getElementById("questionTest");
      element.innerHTML = session.getCurrentItem().primaryText;
      console.log("set text");
      $( "#inputBox" ).focus();
    }
}
```

```css
.typing .typing-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px
}

.typing .typing-wrapper .typing-box {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5.7px 23px;
    height: 57px
}

.typing .typing-wrapper .typing-box:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="central-area" id="central-area">
  <div class="main typing">
    <button class="next-button btn btn-inverse clearfix" id="unique-next-button" onclick="switchPage()" style="display: inline-block;" title="Next [Shortcut : Enter]"><span class="next-icon"></span>
    <div class="next-text">
      Next
    </div></button>
    <div class="question-row row column">
      <div class="graphic"></div>
      <div class="question-text" id="questionText">
        to leave
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hint row column">
      <span class="hint-text">Type the correct <strong>French</strong> for the <strong>English</strong> above:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning typing-alert"></div>
    <div class="typing-wrapper">
      <span class="marking-icon"></span>
      <input autocomplete="off" class="shiny-box typing-box" id="inputBox" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `$( "." )`?  That seems invalid.

Comment: Shouldn't `session.getCurrentItem.itemType` be `session.getCurrentItem().itemType`? Also where is the part that tries to set focus? I only see code adding an event handler to the focus event.

Comment: I made your question into a runnable code snippet

Comment: Thanks - when I copied it over, not sure what happened to the ID, but I went back and added it.

Comment: You're missing the # from your selector still. It should be $( "#inputBox").focus();

Comment: I added the hash tag, but isn't still not setting focus.

Comment: Have you tried simply calling focus() instead of passing a callback to it?

Comment: Yes, that was my first attempt. using getElementbyID and then using focus() but that didn't work.

Comment: So `$("#inputBox").focus();` doesn't work?

Comment: Correct - neither the jQuery nor Javascript versions work.

Comment: Are you certain it reaches that point? Have you fixed the typo on `session.getCurrentItem.itemType`? Any errors in the console?

Comment: yes, I fixed the typo and set an console.log right above the focus and that outputs, so it gets up to it.

Comment: Try printing `$( "#inputBox" ).length` to check if the element exists at that point. Also please change your code above to be `focus()` instead of `focus(callback)`

Comment: I added a console.log of the length immediately before it and it shows 1.

Comment: Could be a race condition where the element isn't actually rendered yet (since you appear to be rendering it in the `render_HTML` method). Maybe try setting focus from within a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and see if it helps.

Comment: The timeout fixed it!

Comment: where you call the JS function "populate()" .. whether you calling or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function populate(){
    render_HTML(session.getCurrentItem().itemType);
    if(session.getCurrentItem().itemType === "multiple choice"){
      //multiple choice 
    }
    else if(session.getCurrentItem().itemType === "typing"){
      var element = document.getElementById("questionTest");
      element.innerHTML = session.getCurrentItem().primaryText;
      console.log("set text");
      $( "#inputBox" ).focus();
    }
}
```

```css
.typing .typing-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px
}

.typing .typing-wrapper .typing-box {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5.7px 23px;
    height: 57px
}

.typing .typing-wrapper .typing-box:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="central-area" id="central-area">
  <div class="main typing">
    <button class="next-button btn btn-inverse clearfix" id="unique-next-button" onclick="switchPage()" style="display: inline-block;" title="Next [Shortcut : Enter]"><span class="next-icon"></span>
    <div class="next-text">
      Next
    </div></button>
    <div class="question-row row column">
      <div class="graphic"></div>
      <div class="question-text" id="questionText">
        to leave
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hint row column">
      <span class="hint-text">Type the correct <strong>French</strong> for the <strong>English</strong> above:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning typing-alert"></div>
    <div class="typing-wrapper">
      <span class="marking-icon"></span>
      <input autocomplete="off" class="shiny-box typing-box" id="inputBox" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```